# PostgreSQLで同じテーブルにそれぞれ別のwhere区指定をしたselect文を結合したいです。

Tags: postgresql

postgreで同じテーブルにそれぞれ別のwhere区指定をしたselect文を結合したいです。

select文に例えますと、

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.id = '50' AND a.id = '55';

 id |   日時   | 最大値 | 最大起時 |
---------------+--------+----------+
 50 | 20200101 | 7.3    |          | 
 55 | 20200101 |        | 15:30    | 
------------------------------------
```

上記の空白をなくして以下の結果のように最大値の隣に最大起時を載せたい感じです。

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.id = '50' AND a.id = '55';

   日時   | 最大値 | 最大起時 |
---------+--------+----------+
 20200101 | 7.3    | 15:30    | 
------------------------------------
```

Comment: 一行で表現したいのでしょうか？それともid 50 の最大起時のフィールドにid 55の15:30を表示したいということですか？望んでいる結果も質問文のテーブル表示のように表現できるとわかりやすいかなと思います・

Comment: 望んでいる結果も表現しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クエリ結果を1行にまとめるには[集約関数](http://tatsuo-ishii.github.io/doc-ja/12.0/functions-aggregate.html)か[COALESCE](http://tatsuo-ishii.github.io/doc-ja/12.0/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)関数で整形する必要があります。

```
-- サンプルデータ
with a as (select 50 id, '20200101' 日付, 7.3 最大値, null 最大起時 union all
           select 55 id, '20200101' 日付, null 最大値, '15:30' 最大起時 union all
           select 60 id, '20200101' 日付, 999 最大値, '00:00' 最大起時)
-- 回答SQL(集約関数のMAXで1行にまとめる)
select   max(日付) 日付, max(最大値) 最大値, max(最大起時) 最大起時
from     a
where    id in (50, 55)
union all
-- 回答SQL(coalesceで1行にまとめる)
select   coalesce(a1.日付, a2.日付) 日付, coalesce(a1.最大値, a2.最大値) 最大値, coalesce(a1.最大起時, a2.最大起時) 最大起時
from     a a1, a a2
where    a1.id = 50
and      a2.id = 55
```